# How to get panel item name in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, panel

I have createad a panal in pandas python using multiple dataframes and a dictionary.
Altough I defined the panal item names myself, I need to filter them out in another piece of code. How do I get the panel item names?

I tried using the panel attribute commands, such as "axes" and "items". However the pandas documentation is rather basic and does not answer this.

Comment: Hmm, panel is deprecated - check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel)

Comment: ok, I see. Well, I guess I need to switch to MultiIndex DF now. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion `panel` is deprecated - check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel), so if want use `pandas` one possible solution is `MultiIndex DataFrame` and if possible the best is convert dictionary for scalars values in `DataFrame` for better performance and for use pandas functions.

Then check:

```
print (df.columns.names)
```

And

```
print (df.index.names)
```

But if want use `panel`:

```
wp = pd.Panel(np.random.randn(2, 5, 4), items=['Item1', 'Item2'],
    major_axis=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=5),
     minor_axis=pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], name='foo'))

print (wp.axes[2].name)
foo
```